# docker-compose healthcheck always says error but there are no error logs

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-healthcheck

I'm trying to understand how the `healthcheck` works but I'm having a hard time figuring it out.  Here is an example `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  kibana_setup:
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:8.7.1
    labels:
      co.elastic.logs/module: kibana
    volumes:
      - ./keystore:/usr/share/kibana/keystore
    user: "0"
    command: >
      bash -c 'echo hello > /usr/share/kibana/keystore/kibana.keystore;'
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "[ -f /usr/share/kibana/keystore/kibana.keystore ]"]
      interval: 1s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 240
  hello_world:
    depends_on:
      kibana_setup:
        condition: service_healthy
    image: hello-world
```

When I run the command `docker-compose up --build -d`, I see this output:

```
[+] Running 3/3
 ✔ Network test_default           Created                                                                                                               0.3s
 ✘ Container test-kibana_setup-1  Error                                                                                                                 0.0s
 ✔ Container test-hello_world-1   Created                                                                                                               0.0s
dependency failed to start: container test-kibana_setup-1 exited (0)
```

And I noticed on my host machine, a file `./keystore/kibana.keystore` was made with the word `hello` in it.

I don't understand why the `test-kibana_setup-1` container failed?  The `healthcheck` should have returned `true` because `./keystore/kibana.keystore` does exist.

The command `docker logs test-kibana_setup-1` also shows nothing.

Have I misunderstood how healthchecks work?

Comment: The `command:` runs _instead of_ the normal thing the container would do; when you set it to just run a trivial `echo` command, it could reasonably exit before the health check has a chance to run at all.  If you're bind-mounting the keystore directory from the host, you might try to set up key material before starting the container.  That process isn't especially programming-related, and another site like [sf] or [devops.se] might be a more appropriate place to ask about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The container is exiting before the health check runs.

I added a tail to this to demonstrate the idea working:

```yaml
services:
  test:
    image: alpine
    command:
      - /bin/sh
      - -c
      - |
        echo hello > /usr/share/test.txt
        tail -f /dev/null
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "[ -f /usr/share/test.txt ]"]
  hello_world:
    depends_on:
      test:
        condition: service_healthy
    image: hello-world
```